# How to marshal json string to bson document for writing to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

What I am looking is equivalent of [Document.parse()](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

in golang, that allows me create bson from json directly? I do not want to create intermediate Go structs for marshaling

Comment: You can choose either you will use some intermediate structs for marshalling/unmarshalling (high level interface) or directly bson, or low level like bson.M, bson.D. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518297/golang-bson-conversion

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson) package has a function called [`UnmarshalJSON`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#UnmarshalJSON) which does exactly what you want.

The `data` parameter should hold you JSON string as `[]byte` value.

```golang
 func UnmarshalJSON(data []byte, value interface{}) error
```

> UnmarshalJSON unmarshals a JSON value that may hold non-standard syntax as defined in BSON's extended JSON specification.

Example:

```
var bdoc interface{}
err = bson.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(`{"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": ["home", "green"]}`),&bdoc)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = c.Insert(&bdoc)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: What about the second parameter value, the documentation doesn't seem to elaborate what type it needs to be?  From, my understanding of go, interface{} is equivalent of void * in C or Object in java ? Pointer to an unmarshalJSON example would be even better

Comment: There is big difference between void* and interface{}. When variable is void* there is no way to find out the type of variable. Whereas interface{} knows the type.

Answer (score 9):

`mongo-go-driver` has a function `bson.UnmarshalExtJSON` that does the job.

Here's the example:

```
var doc interface{}
err := bson.UnmarshalExtJSON([]byte(`{"foo":"bar"}`), true, &doc)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Note here that `doc` will be in `ExtendedJson` which may restructure the input to include the mongo bson type system.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer a way to do this directly with supported libraries (e.g. the mongo-go-driver). You would need to write your own converter based on the bson spec.

Edit: here's one that by now has seen a few Terabytes of use in prod.
https://github.com/dustinevan/mongo/blob/main/bsoncv/bsoncv.go

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to create intermediate Go structs for marshaling

If you do want/need to create an intermediate Go BSON structs, you could use a conversion module such [github.com/sindbach/json-to-bson-go](https://github.com/sindbach/json-to-bson-go). For example:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sindbach/json-to-bson-go/convert"
    "github.com/sindbach/json-to-bson-go/options"
)

func main() {
    doc := `{"foo": "buildfest", "bar": {"$numberDecimal":"2021"} }`
    opt := options.NewOptions()
    result, _ := convert.Convert([]byte(doc), opt)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Will produce output:

```golang
package main

import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

type Example struct {
    Foo string               `bson:"foo"`
    Bar primitive.Decimal128 `bson:"bar"`
}
```

This module is compatible with [the official MongoDB Go driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver), and as you can see it supports [Extended JSON formats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

You can also visit https://json-to-bson-map.netlify.app to try the module in action. You can paste a JSON document, and see the Go BSON structs as output.

Answer (score 1):

A simple converter that uses `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsonrw`:

```
func JsonToBson(message []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    reader, err := bsonrw.NewExtJSONValueReader(bytes.NewReader(message), true)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, err
    }
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer, _ := bsonrw.NewBSONValueWriter(buf)
    err = bsonrw.Copier{}.CopyDocument(writer, reader)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, err
    }
    marshaled := buf.Bytes()
    return marshaled, nil
}
```